# Efficient time-weighted averages

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

given a dataset containing short intervals, and a value representing an average measure of something over each interval, I would like to average those values up to the calendar year, separately for each individual ("id").

The issue is that these intervals are not aligned with calendar year, so time-weighting of those values is necessary in order to get the best estimate of the annual average from the shorter interval averages.

Note that the intervals are inclusive for the start date and exclusive for the end date.

Example data

`start_date` and `end_date` are intervals that are unique non-overlapping within levels of `id`:

```
  set.seed(30)

library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
x <- CJ(id=1:5, start_date=seq(from=as.Date("2005-01-12"),by=14,length=100))

#add noise so intervals don't all start on 2005-01-12
x[,start_date:=start_date + rbinom(1,size=20,prob=.15)*15L,by=id]

#all intervals are two weeks:
x[,end_date:=start_date+14]

x[,value:=rnorm(nrow(x))]

#for each id, calculate the mean value over each calendar year. 
years <- c(year(min(x$start_date)), year(max(x$start_date)))
```

Additional constraints:

- works for intervals that aren't exactly two weeks long
- works even if the intervals aren't all the same length (as long as
  they're non-overlapping)
- works even if the earliest start_date isn't the same for each
  participant
- averages for calendar years that are don't have enough periods for
  that id to complete the year should be NA

Potential solution that is too slow for my purposes.

```
complete_date_seq <- seq(as.Date(ymd(paste0(years[1],"-01-01"))), as.Date(ymd(paste0(years[2],"-12-12"))),by=1)

m <- matrix(NA,nrow=length(unique(x$id)),ncol=length(complete_date_seq))
rownames(m) <- unique(x$id)
colnames(m) <- as.character(complete_date_seq)

for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  temp <- x[id==rownames(m)[i]]
  for(j in 1:nrow(temp)){
    m[i, as.Date(complete_date_seq) %within% temp[j,interval(start_date,end_date-1)]] <- temp[j,value]
  }

}

out <- CJ(id=unique(x$id),year=years[1]:years[2])

intervalfromyear <- function(y)  interval(as.Date(ymd(paste0(y,"-01-01"))), as.Date(ymd(paste0(y,"-12-31"))))


out[, annual_avg:=mean(m[rownames(m)==.BY$id,complete_date_seq %within% intervalfromyear(.BY$year)]) ,by=c("id","year")]
```

I'm guessing there's some package for doing time-weighting that I'm not aware of. Is this true? Ideally there's a native data.table solution that's fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same approach I posed in the question but a lot more efficient since it creates a long data.table rather than a matrix. I spent some time looking for a different solution (that doesn't actually involve actually creating a cell for each date and instead uses a weighted average product formula) using foverlaps but it was way more work, less easily extensible, and more error-prone.

```
#switch from exclusive to inclusive end_date
x[, actual_end_date:=as.Date(as.numeric(end_date)-1,origin="1970-01-01")]

z <- x[, list(date=seq(start_date,actual_end_date,by=1),value),by=c("id","start_date")]


complete_date_seq <- seq(from=as.Date(paste0(years[1],"-01-01")),
                         to=as.Date(paste0(years[2],"-12-31")),by=1)

missing_dates <- z[,list(date=as.Date(setdiff( complete_date_seq,date ),origin="1970-01-01"),value=NA),by=id]

result <- rbind(z,missing_dates,fill=TRUE)[order(id,date)]
result[, year:=substr(date,1,4)]
result[, mean(value),by=c("id","year")]
```